# Typescript dynamic filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have array of objects, I want to make a dynamic filter which means just pass a value without key to search every key value on object and returns the matched objects. Same as the angular material table which filter all column

```
[
   {
      "id":4,
      "email":"eve.holt@reqres.in",
      "first_name":"Eve",
      "last_name":"Holt",
      "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg",
      "date":"2020-02-24T13:19:08.630025Z"

},
   {
      "id":5,
      "email":"charles.morris@reqres.in",
      "first_name":"Charles",
      "last_name":"Morris",
      "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg",
      "date":"2020-02-24T13:19:08.630025Z"

},
   {
      "id":6,
      "email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
      "first_name":"Tracey",
      "last_name":"Ramos",
      "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg",
      "date":"2020-02-24T13:19:08.630025Z"

}
]
```

Also I want to be able to filter on date

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: In addition to showing what you have tried and explaining what specific problem you have, you should also be clear about requirements - for your own sake as much as anything else. What if a value is an array or a number? Should it be a case-sensitive search? This is not a trivial problem, and you're not going to get someone to write a working solution for you - especially without clear requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, assuming `data` contains your array of objects.
`filtered` contains the results with the matched objects.

```
const search = 'yourValue';
const filtered = data.filter(obj => {
  return !!JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj)).match(new RegExp(search, 'i'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lunr](https://lunrjs.com/docs/index.html) for a lightweight full text search implementation. For date filtering you can use [Crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter).